# show records in Angularjs - newbie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

This is a real newbie question:

I have a view for my index in Rails in erb:

```
<div ng-app="Donor">
  <div ng-controller="DonorCtrl">

    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="donor in donors">
      {{donor}}
    </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

my Donor json returned from Rails is:

```
class DonorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :tools_id, :first_name, :last_name
end
```

My javascript file has this;

```
var app;

app = angular.module("Donor", ["ngResource"]);

    // separate view to Add new donors

 $scope.addDonor = function() {
   var donor;
   donor = Entry.save($scope.newDonor);
   $scope.donors.push(entry);
   return $scope.newDonor = {};
 };

 $scope.showDonors = function() {
  var Donor = $resource("/donors", {
    update: {
        method: "GET"
    }
 });
 return $scope.donors = Donor;

}

this.DonorCtrl = function($scope, $resource) {
  var Donor;
  Donor = $resource("/donors/:id", {
    id: "@id"
}, {
    update: {
        method: "PUT"
    }
});
return $scope.donors = Donor.query();
};
```

How do I get a list of donors to in my index view?

I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your first issues was that you did not have the right code inside of the controller. I also turned your $resource's into factory's. I changed the Donors update method to 'PUT' since you have an 'addDonor' method.

Make sure you also have the proper libraries setup for angularjs. For this you will need:

```
angular.js
angular-resource.js
```

The altered Javascript:

```
var app;

app = angular.module("Donor", ["ngResource"]);

app.factory("Donors", [
  "$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/donors", {}, {
      update: {
        method: "PUT"
      }
    });
  }
]);

app.factory("Donor", [
  "$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/donors/:id", {
      id: "@id"
    }, {
      update: {
        method: "GET"
      }
    });
  }
]);

this.DonorCtrl = [
  "$scope", "Donor", "Donors", function($scope, Donor, Donors) {
    var donor;
    $scope.donor = Donor.query();
    $scope.donors = Donors.query();
    $scope.addDonor = function() {};
    donor = Donor.save($scope.newDonor)(function() {
      return $scope.donors.push(donor);
    });
    return $scope.newDonor = {};
  }
];
```

Since you are using rails, here is the coffeescript version (I find it elegant in combination with angularjs):

```
app = angular.module("Donor", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Donors", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
    $resource("/donors", {}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
]
app.factory "Donor", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
    $resource("/donors/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "GET"}})
]

@DonorCtrl = ["$scope", "Donor", "Donors", ($scope, Donor, Donors) ->
  $scope.donor = Donor.query()
  $scope.donors = Donors.query()

  $scope.addDonor = ->
        donor = Donor.save($scope.newDonor) ->
            $scope.donors.push donor
        $scope.newDonor = {}
]
```

I would checkout [EggHead.io](http://egghead.io/) for a better understanding of how to setup your angular javascript files.

Comment: Factories are hard to find much information about - I have watched most of the videos and they are great